# ContentBlockbyID is only rendering in send preview

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, content-builder

I have an Email that contains various ContentBlockbyID references. The Email looks fine when I open it in send/preview. But in view mode in content builder or when I configure it in a Journey, I only see the code like

```
%%=ContentBlockbyID("583")=%%%%=ContentBlockbyID("586")=%%%%=ContentBlockbyID("587")=%%%%=ContentBlockbyID("588")=%%%%=ContentBlockbyID("517")=%%
```

I would actually expect that the code gets rendered. Any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the new Reference block that was added in the August release. It accomplishes the same thing (and it actually uses that same AMPscript function), but it will render the block in the Content Builder editor when you're editing a template or email.

Comment: It is exactly what I am using. And is totally fine when editing. But it is a blocker for my client not to have this rendered view in the journey builder as well. People think that the Email is broken when they only see ContentBlockbyID code snippets. In addition not everybody has the the needed access rights to edit. Therefore they have no chance to see what the Email looks like.

Comment: OK, thanks for that info. I'll pass it along to the Journey Builder team.

Comment: Thanks. Also the "Engagement decisions" links cannot be used within the JB anymore if working with the ContentBlockbyID. Therefore no option to use it as of now.

Answer (score 0):

The system processes the AMPscript at the point where you include it in the message to render content on a subscriber-by-subscriber basis.

Salesforce Marketing Cloud application handles all AMPscript calls at the end of the email send/send preview whereas during the view mode/Journey configuration the script won't be executed - thus only showing you the unexecuted script.

Comment: Thanks. What are the possible options to get around this? The reason why I choose content referencing, that I want changes of content blocks reflected in the Email.

Comment: I am a bit confused here with what you're trying to achieve. Could you please explain your concerns? It's a salesforce marketing cloud behaviour that ampscript appears unexecuted in view mode or journey configurations. Also note that the contentblockbyid ampscript function will execute properly if the content blocks are present.

Comment: Use case is that we want to be able create content blocks. The content blocks contain for example specific text. The blocks are used in various Emails. If a user then edits a content block, the changes need to be automatically applied to the Emails that use the content block.